# Custom legend with R leaflet- circles and squares in same plot legends

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I would like to create a leaflet map that has both circles and squares in the same leaflet plot legend.

I have so far used the suggestion found in a previous post and added the following code in my shiny UI code.

```
   tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body   {width:100%;height:100%}",
                       ".leaflet .legend i{
  position: 'topleft';
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  }
")
```

In this way I have although only circles in the legend while I would like to have 3 types of legends: 1) filled circles, 2) empty circles (only  border) and 3) filled squared.

How could I make such a legend using leaflet for R?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code is based entirely on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37482936/8099834) answer, with a few modifications to make "empty" circles and "squares". As explained in that post, the values given to `addLegend` are used literally to make legend shapes, so additional styling can be added.

1. Filled circles: explained in the above answer.
2. Empty circles: set `color:white;` and add `border:3px solid black;` to produce a white circle with a black outline.
3. Filled squares: Adjust `border-radius`. Circles have 50% radius, whereas squares have 0% radius.

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

#create data
Points<-data.frame(x=runif(10,20,21), y=runif(10,0,1), var=rep(c(5,10),5))
map = leaflet() %>% addTiles()

# Set up shiny app
shinyApp(
    ui = bootstrapPage(
        tags$style(type = "text/css", 
                   "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}",
                   ".leaflet .legend i{
                   width: 10px;
                   height: 10px;
                   margin-top: 4px;
                   }
                   "
                   ),
        leafletOutput("myMap", width = "100%", height = "100%")
        ),

    server = function(input, output){

        # set legend features
        colors <- c("red", "white", "blue", "white", "blue", "red")
        labels <- c("filled_square", "empty_square", "big_square", "empty_circle", "filled_circle", "big_circle")
        sizes <- c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30)
        shapes <- c("square", "square", "square", "circle", "circle", "circle")
        borders <- c("red", "blue", "black", "blue", "blue", "black")

        addLegendCustom <- function(map, colors, labels, sizes, shapes, borders, opacity = 0.5){

            make_shapes <- function(colors, sizes, borders, shapes) {
                shapes <- gsub("circle", "50%", shapes)
                shapes <- gsub("square", "0%", shapes)
                paste0(colors, "; width:", sizes, "px; height:", sizes, "px; border:3px solid ", borders, "; border-radius:", shapes)
            }
            make_labels <- function(sizes, labels) {
                paste0("<div style='display: inline-block;height: ", 
                       sizes, "px;margin-top: 4px;line-height: ", 
                       sizes, "px;'>", labels, "</div>")
            }

            legend_colors <- make_shapes(colors, sizes, borders, shapes)
            legend_labels <- make_labels(sizes, labels)

            return(addLegend(map, colors = legend_colors, labels = legend_labels, opacity = opacity))
        }

        output$myMap = renderLeaflet({map %>% 
                addCircleMarkers(Points$x,Points$y,radius=Points$var) %>%
                addLegendCustom(colors, labels, sizes, shapes, borders)
        })
    }
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Hallie, can you please help me at exporting and saving the map coming from your code? I am able to replicate your idea but I do not know how to save the map even if I include a download botton..

Comment: @MarcoMello have you tried [mapshot](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview) as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44261618/8099834) or the [easyPrint plugin](https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint) as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49640636/8099834)? If neither option works for you, open a new question and I can try helping you there. Good luck!