# Circles in legend for leaflet map with addCircleMarkers in R - without shiny

Tags: javascript, css, r, leaflet

I am creating a leaflet map in R - I don't need to build a shiny app, and haven't tackled that particular skill set yet!

I was trying to follow along with this post here to create circles in my legend:
[Creating legend with circles leaflet R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446283/creating-legend-with-circles-leaflet-r/37482936?noredirect=1#comment103326564_37482936) .

However, I'm not sure how to incorporate the `tags$style` attribute to my R code as @K. Rhode suggested to ensure the legend items are circles. In my code, the legend comes up with squares. So close!

**Can anyone help me nudge this code into making the legend items circles?**

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

#create data
Points<-data.frame(x=runif(10,20,21), y=runif(10,0,1), 
                   var=c(rep(c(10,20, 40),3), 20))
Points <- Points %>% 
  mutate(Category = case_when(var == 10 ~ "A", 
                              var == 20 ~ "B",
                              TRUE ~ "C"),
         color = case_when(Category == "A" ~ "blue",
                           Category == "B" ~ "blue",
                           TRUE ~ "red"))


map = leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles()

addLegendCustom <- function(map, colors, labels, sizes, opacity = 0.5){
  colorAdditions <- paste0(colors, "; width:", sizes, "px; height:", sizes, "px")
  labelAdditions <- paste0("<div style='display: inline-block;height: ", 
                           sizes, "px;margin-top: 4px;line-height: ", sizes, "px;'>", 
                           labels, "</div>")

  return(addLegend(map, colors = colorAdditions, 
                   labels = labelAdditions, opacity = opacity))
}


map %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(Points$x,Points$y,radius=Points$var, 
                   color = Points$color, 
                   stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
  addLegendCustom(colors = c("blue", "blue", "red"), 
                  labels = c("A", "B", "C"), sizes = c(10, 20, 40))
```

### In the legend I'd prefer circle markers... not squares as below!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the original answer, you omitted one set of global style definition that is responsible for the round shape.

Add `border-radius: 50%;` to the `colorAdditions` set of css styles, which is the one style you are needing from it.

This would make:

```
  colorAdditions <- paste0(colors, "; border-radius: 50%; width:", sizes, "px; height:", sizes, "px")
```

A bit hacky, but works.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for the quick response! The sizes seem a bit off, but I can adjust that.

Comment: @K.Rohde Could you please let us know how to add a title for the legend? Also, how to add a black boundary for the legend circles? Thanks