# Proportional Symbols Legend in Leaflet for R

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am mapping boardings at transit stops as circle markers using `radius = ~Ons` to create a continuous graduated symbols map. I am wondering if there is a way to make a legend in `Leaflet` for R where the size of the circles in the legend correspond with the level of boardings. Do I need to impose some bins to make this work? Most of the examples I have found are about choropleth maps, but I want the color of the symbols to remain unchanged.

I tried to follow example 1.7 from [this](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/307862_b8c8460272dc4a2a9023d033d5f3ec34.html) page but I get an error message:

> *argument "colors" is missing with no default*.

I tried adding `pal = "#55cc00"`, but then I get the following error message:

> *no applicable method for 'metaData' applied to an object of class "NULL"*.

I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505589/circles-in-legend-for-leaflet-map-with-addcirclemarkers-in-r-without-shiny) post but it doesn't seem to transfer entirely because the data is categorical.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks for the help

```
ridership_25<- leaflet()%>%
  setView(-75.1213, lat = 39.97266, zoom = 12)%>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Wikimedia)%>%
  addPolylines(data = line_25, 
               color = 'tomato', 
               weight = 1.5)%>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = the_25, 
             color = 'tomato', 
             radius = ~Ons, 
             fillOpacity = 0.4, 
             popup = paste("Route: ", the_25$LineAbbr, "<br>",
                           "Direction: ", the_25$Direction, "<br>",
                            "Boards: ", the_25$Ons, "<br>",
                           "Alights: ", the_25$Offs))%>%
  addLegend("bottomright", values = ~Ons, title = "Boardings, opacity = 0.6")

ridership_25
```

Would it be helpful if I showed some of the `the_25` dataset? Not sure the best way to do that with an `sf` object.